# Conditional Triggers does not have performence improvement?

Tags: database, sqlite, triggers

This is related to conditional triggers of SQLITE3.

Consider, For example, that I have update trigger on a table T as

```
CREATE TRIGGER AfterUpdateOnT
AFTER UPDATE ON T
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    Update table T1 where new.value = 1;
    Update table T2 where new.value = 2;
    .
    .
    .
    .
END;
```

So, Does it make sense to split them up into various triggers as :

```
CREATE TRIGGER AfterUpdateOnTWhen1
AFTER UPDATE ON T
WHEN new.value = 1
BEGIN
    UPDATE TABLE T1 SET VALUE = new.value;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER AfterUpdateOnTWhen2
AFTER UPDATE ON T
WHEN new.value = 2
BEGIN
   UPDATE TABLE T2 SET VALUE = new.value;
END;
```

AND SO ON. WOULD THAT HELP IN ANY PERFORMANCE IMPROVEMENT ?

Comment: This is probably the `condition` check.

Comment: I modified the question after verifying that conditional triggers are called only after meeting specific conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether a particular WHEN claus helps depends on how much the equivalent WHERE clause could be optimized.

In this particular case, the `WHERE new.value = 1` filter, if not true, shortcuts the entire execution of the UPDATE statment, so it should have the same performance.

In the general case, it's possible that the WHERE filter cannot be optimized as well because it is combined with some other conditions in the query.

There is no situation where using WHEN would be less performant than WHERE, so if you care about performance, you probably should use WHEN.
However, splitting the trigger into two makes the schema more complex, so you should do this only if you actually have a performance problem, or if the separate WHEN clause document better what's going on.

Comment: I verified with multiple tests that there is no improvement by splitting these into multiple triggers. Splitting of triggers is overhead for maintenance and documentation. So, I accept this answer because now I agree to your explanation of "Shortcutting of execution".